# Get Request Cookie from website with Curl in PHP

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping

I want to get the Request Cookie from a website using the curl method in PHP. Is this possible or not? I tried with curl but it just gets a Response Cookie and I don't know how request cookie works. Can someone help me?

Example code:

```
<?php
$url = "https://www.ebay.com/";

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);

$response = curl_exec($ch);


  $header_size = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
  $headers = substr($response, 0, $header_size);
  $body = substr($response, $header_size);

curl_close($ch);


print($headers)
?>
```

I want to get request cookie based on screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: thnks @ggorlen i was edited my post

Comment: Can you post your header printout string and point to the cookie(s) you're interested in? Is it the `Set-cookie: xxxxxxxxxxx;` properties from the header?

Comment: @ggorlen this printout headers

[link](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/M1n007/05d174e8b41452876bfe0ebd4973bca8/raw/149971f6bfbf6724afccdcc350a029c8fd40b138/adasd)

I do not get the ak_bmsc cookie

Comment: If the cookie you're expecting is the `D7A6EFF86...` one and you don't see that in the header, then it appears to be more than a parsing problem here. You'll need to post more details explaining which value you're interested in, what your current output is, etc, for me to be able to diagnose the situation. Sorry.